# view cart button redirect same page in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce in my wordpress site
All are the latest version I am using but I found a error
woocommerce related all link like "view cart", "checkout" button are redirecting the same page the current url
How can I solve this?

Here is my site link
http://localbmx.com.au/wordpress/?post_type=product

Comment: check your woocommerce pagesettings. You might have mixed up the pages

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this by setting the page. Goto http://yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=woocommerce_settings&tab=pages

And set pages for cart from dropdown menu.

Answer (score 3):

You can add cart page and enter this short-code `[woocommerce_cart]` in it.
also for checkout add new page and enter `[woocommerce_checkout]`.

Then in the dashboard go to  *Woo Commerce > Settings > Checkou*t  in ***Checkout Pages*** section the pages for cart and checkout.

Answer (score 1):

saintush had the correct answer but it changed! The link is now

```
www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=checkout
```

(In the WordPress Admin: Woo Commerce > Settings > Checkout)

Answer (score 1):

For me the link was `http://www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=advanced` for wooCommerce version 3.4.2. It's been under `Advanced` tab.

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce changed some settings. So now to set woo pages manually Go to the WooCommerce > Settings > Advance and set pages for cart, Checkout, My Account etc.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Change Some Woocomerce Setting

In Woocomerce Version 3.6.4

```
Go to dashboard > WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced > Page setup
```

[image]